# F# - The type was expected to have type Async<'a> but has string -> Asnyc<'a> instead

Tags: asynchronous, f#, httpwebrequest, streamreader

After shamelessly pilfering a code snippet from Tomas Petricek's Blog:
http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-fsharp-async-intro.aspx
Specifically, this one (and making a few alterations to it):

```
     let downloadPage(url:string) (postData:string) = async {
  let request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
// Asynchronously get response and dispose it when we're done
  use! response = request.AsyncGetResponse()
  use stream = response.GetResponseStream()
  let temp = new MemoryStream()
  let buffer = Array.zeroCreate 4096 

   // Loop that downloads page into a buffer (could use 'while' 
   // but recursion is more typical for functional language)
  let rec download() = async { 
   let! count = stream.AsyncRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
   do! temp.AsyncWrite(buffer, 0, count)
   if count > 0 then return! download() }

   // Start the download asynchronously and handle results
  do! download()
  temp.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore
  let html = (new StreamReader(temp)).ReadToEnd()
  return html };;
```

I tried to do the following with it, and got the error on the last line:

> The type was expected to have type `Async<'a>` but has `string -> Asnyc<'a>` instead

I googled the error but couldn't find anything that revealed my particular issue.

```
let postData = "userid=" + userId + "&password=" + password + "&source=" + sourceId + "&version=" + version
let url = postUrlBase + "100/LogIn?" + postData
Async.RunSynchronously (downloadPage(url, postData));;
```

Also, how would I modify the code so that it downloads a non-ending byte stream (but with occasional pauses between each burst of bytes) asynchronously instead of a string?  How would I integrate reading this byte stream as it comes through?  I realize this is more than one question, but since they are are all closely related I figured one question would save some time.

Thanks in advance,

Bob

P.S.  As I am still new to F# please feel free to make any alterations/suggestions to my code which shows how its done in a more functional style.  I'm really trying to get out of my C# mindset, so I appreciate any pointers anyone may wish to share.

Edit:  I accidentally pasted in the wrong snippet I was using. I did make an alteration to Tomas' snippet and forgot about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I attempt to run your code `downloadPage(url, postData)` doesn't work as `downloadPage` expects two seperate strings. `downloadPage url postData` is what is expected.

If you changed the `let` binding to tuple form, or `let downloadPage(url:string, postData:string)` your call would have worked as well.

To explain why you got the error you got is more complicated. Curried form creates a function that returns a function or `string -> string -> Async<string>` in your case. The compiler therefore saw you passing a single parameter (tuples are single items after all) and saw that the result would have to be a `string -> Async<string>` which is not compatible with `Async<string>`. Another error it could have found (and did in my case) is that `string * string` is not compatible with `string`. The exact error being `Expected string but found 'a * 'b`.

Comment: I accidentally pasted in the wrong snippet I was using.  I did make an alteration to Tomas' snippet and forgot about it.  Since you're the only person who gave it a shot feel free to change your answer to something like I posted below and I'll give it to you.  It would be a little shady to answer my own question when the question couldn't have been answered orginaly.  :)

Comment: @Beaker: There you go, also explained the discrepancy, including the logic behind the different error I received and referenced in my initial submission.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the initial mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had:

```
Async.RunSynchronously (downloadPage(url, postData));;
```

this is what worked after continued random guessing:

```
Async.RunSynchronously (downloadPage url postData);;
```

Although, I'm not sure why this change fixed the problem.  Thoughts?